# Infinite product: Problem I

Tags: limits, gamma-function, infinite-product

What is the closed form value of the infinite product
$$
\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left\{\frac{1}{e^{2qx}}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{2nq+qx}\left(1-\frac{x}{2n-1}\right)^p\left(1+\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)^p\right\} ?
$$
In particular, what are the values for the cases:

1. $q=1$, $p=2$, $x=1$
2. $q=1$, $p=-2$, $x=1$
3. $q=1$, $p=-2$, $x=2$ ?

*Notes:*

As asked by a fellow member the problem is a generalization of the problem found in Mathproblems journal, Volume 4, Issue 2 (2014), p. 264, Problem 99, proposed by Li Yin.

Comment: Where does this come from ? Why do you believe it has a closed form ?

Comment: @TheGame  This problem is a generalization of a problem proposed in a math journal's problem column.

Comment: Could you add the problem this one comes from then ? Providing context could help.

Comment: If you squint, the first two terms look like the Weierstrass product for the Gamma function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html

See (16).